# ScreenShot Detection in whole App from single Page in ios

Tags: ios, swift, screenshot

Screenshot prevention is not possible that i Understand but we can do the same as snapchatdoes,We can Detect it.

My application consist of more than 10+ controller so on every page addobserver is bit tedious so want the solution if i can place it on appdelegate/Scenedelegate or any other so that on whichever controller screenshot Captured i l be notified.Placing is the main required thing here

Something like reachability which works in similar way for network detection

Here is the Code :

```
 func detectScreenShot(action: @escaping () -> ()) {
       UIScreen.main.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "captured", options: .new, context: nil)
        
        let mainQueue = OperationQueue.main
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification, object: nil, queue: mainQueue) { notification in
            // executes after screenshot
            print(notification)
            action()
        }
    }



override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if (keyPath == "captured") {
            let isCaptured = UIScreen.main.isCaptured
          
            print(isCaptured)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Screenshot detection is different to screen capture and mirroring. You can subscribe to the screenshot notification in any object that is convenient https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-detect-when-the-user-takes-a-screenshot

Comment: @Paulw11 I have added the same observer which has pointed in the link and also in above code but this i have to add in all the controllers which i dont want .I want the logic in which i have to add it once and will work in whole app

Comment: As I said you can add the observer in any object you like. You can add it in the app delegate if you like.

Comment: @Paulw11 but when i add in appdelegate it wont detect the screenshot on other pages.for every page i have to add these lines of code but i dont want that i want one function at one place that handle the screenshot detection from everycontroller like reachability

Comment: I am not sure what you mean?  A notification is posted when a screenshot occurs. That notification will be delivered to the closure you have registered.  You can observe the notification in your app delegate or wherever is convenient.  There is no need to specifically observe the notification in each view controller.

Comment: @Paulw11 but on placing in appdelegate didfinishlaunching it wont post any event when screenshot detects

Comment: I just tested exactly that. It detected every screenshot

Comment: Can u send me d demo of that???@Paulw11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221679/discussion-between-paulw11-and-aashi).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement this by making a BaseViewController,And all the other View Controllers should be inherited by the BaseViewController,So u just have to observe the screenshot detection in BaseViewController and you don't have to write the code on every ViewController

Comment: Can u please Show the Demo of that??coz i dont know how to achieve it